# Typechecker for a C/C++ like language

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-construction, typechecking, bnfc

Currently I am working on a compiler for a C/C++ like language to be more specific a typechecker.
I have generated a parser with a grammar and the bnfc tool. For my typechecker I need to infer the type of expressions. All expressions are derived from a abstract base class Exp like the following:

```
class Exp {
...
}

class ExpPlus : public {
 ...
}

class ExpAnd : public {
 ...
} 
...
```

ExpPlus refers to `Exp + Exp` and ExpAnd to `Exp && Exp` respectively.
My infer function takes a Expression and returns it's type and looks like this:

```
ype *TypeChecker::infer(Exp *exp)
{
    // check for kind of expression
    /* Base cases */
    if(dynamic_cast<ETrue*>(exp))
    {
        Type *tBool = new Type_bool;
        return tBool;
    }
    if(dynamic_cast<EFalse*>(exp))
    {
        Type *tBool = new Type_bool;
        return tBool;
    }
    if(dynamic_cast<EInt*>(exp))
    {
        Type *tInt = new Type_int;
        return tInt;
    }
    if(dynamic_cast<EDouble*>(exp))
    {
        Type *tDouble = new Type_double;
        return tDouble;
    }
    if(dynamic_cast<EId*>(exp))   // search for type of given Id in contexts
    {
        EId *eId = dynamic_cast<EId*>(exp);

        Type *typeOfSearchedId = env_->lookupVarTypeFromContext(eId->id_);
        return typeOfSearchedId;
    }
    /* Base cases end*/

    /* check expressions */
    if(dynamic_cast<EApp*>(exp))
    {
        EApp *eApp = dynamic_cast<EApp*>(exp);
        Type *retType = env_->lookupFunTypeFromSymbolTable(eApp->id_).returnType;

        return retType;
    }
    if(dynamic_cast<EUPlus*>(exp))
    {
        // cast exp to type of exp
        EUPlus *eu_plus = dynamic_cast<EUPlus*>(exp);

        // infer till base case is derived
        Type *typeExp = infer(eu_plus->exp_);

        // if type is int or double
        if(dynamic_cast<Type_int*>(typeExp) || dynamic_cast<Type_double*>(typeExp))
            return typeExp;

        throw TypeException("Trying to unary add wrong type: " + env_->getStringRepresentationOfType(typeExp));
    }
...
```

As you can see I have a long list of If-statements that checker of which concrete expression type the expression is, it works fine and stuff but I wonder whether there is any more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: chain of `if(dynamic_cast<....` means that you are still not aware how polymorphism should be used.

Comment: use virtual functions instead of dynamic casts

Comment: please note that the code you posted is, no offense, a little messed up. `: public` without mentioning the base class, `;` missing after class definitions, `infer` is so incomplete, that it is difficult to understand what it actually does. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: You should look into the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got polymorphism the wrong way around.

Instead of this:

```
class Base {};

class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Base {};
class Derived3 : public Base {};
//...

void foo(Base* b) {
    if(dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(b)) {
        do_something( dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(b));
    } else if (dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(b)) {
        do_something( dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(b));
    } else if ....
}
```

You should acutally make use of polymorhism by using virtual methods:

```
class Base {
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    void do_something() override { /*...*/ }
};
class Derived2 : public Base {
    void do_something() override { /*...*/ }
};
//...

void foo(Base* b) {
    b->do_something();
}
```

Note how now not every method that uses `Base*` and expects different behavior depending on the dynamic type must actually know the dynamic type. `foo` just calls `do_something` and virtual dispatch selects the right method to be called. If you write some `bar(Base*)` you do not need a second block of `if-else` but rather call virtual methods again.

I simplified the example a lot, though it seems like in your code all branches return a `type` and the only difference is different implementations for different derived classes.

Comment: It's generally preferred to use the visitor pattern instead of having the AST classes contain a method for each compilation phase. In my opinion it makes much more sense to have all the type checking logic in a file dedicated to type checking and all the code generation logic in a file dedicated to code generation etc. than to have it spread out over all the different AST classes.

Comment: @sepp2k I admit that I only focused on the usage of polymorphism and ignored the actual use-case. tbh I think anything is better than what OP currently has ;)